# What tools are available for analysing the time a browser spends processing a page

Tags: performance, browser, client-side

We are performance tuning our web site at the moment and have the main page content down to a respectable 65ms for firefox to grab it (from request to finish receiving the html).

Caching means there is generally no other content that needs to be requested from the server (after the initial page view).

However, firefox is spending **another 400ms until onload fires**. I assume this is the time it takes firefox to parse our html, fetch images, css and js from the cache, parse the css and js and render the page.

So, my question is, **how can I drill into this 400ms of dead time and find out where most of it is being spent?** eg. if I knew that css parsing was taking a long time, I could review that and turn it up as needed.

I don't really have any tools with enough sophistication for doing this. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:** I know when the resources (like images etc) are loading. It is the other time, after the resources load I am trying to look at. YSlow don't help with this area.

Comment: Answer updated regarding your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to firebug and yslow mentioned by Tim S Van Haren, there's also [Page speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) by google, also a firebug add-on.

---

Edit: Crockford recommends in his talks about javascript to use [Dynatrace](http://www.dynatrace.com) for IE, or the developers tools in chrome. Apparently, Firefox doesn't have the extensions for that level of precision yet, but it may have changed since the talk

And there's also [this previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214368/measure-cpu-load-of-javascript-applications) on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with the [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) add-on are great tools for seeing what resources are taking the longest to load.

Comment: As you want to use Firefox, this is the top solution. Chrome has something similar built-in; I am not sure about others.

Comment: Yes, I use this, but this only really shows the resources loading. I need to see when the browser is parsing css, rendering the page and executing javascript as well. No resources are loading in the 400ms patch at the end...

Comment: Your performance problem is happening in Firefox, so you have to diagnose it in firefox. There might be one in some other browser, but it could have a different cause (and solution). YSlow should show you processing time as well as load time.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) a try.  You can watch the HTTP traffic from several browsers and see a page's resources' load times.